# Proof of construction of inscribed regular hexagon

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I honestly do not know why I'm so lost here, but I am. Really, I'm proving the construction of an equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle, but the inscribed regular hexagon is crucial to that proof (at least the way I'm proving). There are proofs online, but they are not satisfying to me. Here is my question. So, we construct a circle, then label any point P on the circle, then we swing 6 arcs across the circumference of the circle starting at point P and end on our original point while keeping the compass set to the length of the radius of the circle. Does this process not imply that the circumference of a circle is 6 times the radius? We know that this is not true... what am I missing here?

Comment: `Does this process not imply that the circumference of a circle is 6 times the radius` No, why would it? What it *does* imply is that the *perimeter* of the regular hexagon is 6 times the radius.

Comment: Was still initially confused with this comment, but now I see. The chord that connects each of those points is equal to the radius instead of the curved distance between each point... sheesh, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not mean anything about the circumference of the circle. You are not measuring the circumference with your compass.

You just measure the cord not the the length of the arc.

Comment: Yes, I just now noticed that (see comment above). Duh... thank you.

Comment: @TyeCampbell Thanks for attention.